# Delete element from a list, with multiple lists to check -- what's a good way to implement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns

I created state within App.js for a single page application (kanban board)

Within the state i have three key values with arrays and one other key value:

```
    this.state = {
      currentItem: { text: '' },
      toDoListItems: [
        { text: 'hello world' }
      ],
      inProgressListItems: [],
      doneListItems: []
    }
```

Currently my implementation of use cases like delete a task from any board, is implemented by passing the name of the list item.

ie. `{() => this.deleteItem(item, "toDoListItems")}`

How should i make my code more extensible? I was thinking first, I should place all the lists within an object within state. But is it good/bad practice to manually iterate and which array contains the element that I'm looking for? It feels like if i were to do that, I'm making redundant checks.

Comment: Have you considered one list where each object has a key called `list`? The value of list would be "todo", "inProgress", or "done". When rendering the items, you can simply filter the list down

Comment: Hmm I haven't considered that yet @Nick ! That makes it really straight forward for the deleting part. Although now when I'm trying to place the lists into components, I'm facing an issue.. idk if I'm understanding you right, but when you say filter the list down before render, it's within the component itself?